# How do i set copy and paste destination?

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to copy and paste from one workbook to another, but I want to have dynamic names - now are statitic and declared in code.

From the code below is visible how it is set now. How can i change my code  so these names will be automatic based on the cell (eg.: destination  now is "ToThere.xslx" to a value that is in a cell "O2")

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim Name as Short
 Name = Range("O2").Value

 'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("FromHere.xlsm").Worksheets("List1")

 ' I would like this part here to be: Workbooks(Name).Worksheets("List1")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("ToThere.xlsx").Worksheets("List1")

 '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in 
  column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
   lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, 
  "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

 '3. Copy & Paste Data
   wsCopy.Range("A2:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
   wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
```

Comment: **in a cell "O2"** of which sheet? Basically, that code line should be transformed in `Set wsDest = Workbooks(appropriateSheet.Range("O2).value).Worksheets("List1")`.

Comment: "O2" in "List1"

Comment: In "List1" of "FromHere.xlsm" workbook, I suppose. If so: `Set wsDest = Workbooks(wsCopy.Range("O2).value).Worksheets("List1")'

Comment: `Dim dwbName As String: dwbName = Range("O2").Value: Set wsDest = Workbooks(dwbName).Worksheets("List1")`? Surely we can be more helpful if you reveal what you really need.

Comment: @VBasic2008 to avoid going into code for changing names of workbooks because they are named based on the year - this year it is Book2021, next year it will be Book2022, or it is just simply renamed, so I would like to write them into Cell "O2" for vba to automatically change them or get this string and replace it with the old one. I also tried your code but got "Runtime Error - 9.
'Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Book2021.xlsm").Worksheets("List1")' If "O2" is "Book23"then the code should be 'Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Book23.xlsm").Worksheets("List1")'
I hope i explained it more clearly

Comment: Cell O2 of source sheet?

Comment: The error occurred because you don't have the workbook open: `dwbName = "C:\Test\" & Range("O2").Value & ".xlsx": Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open(dwbName).Worksheets("List1")`. Or if it's open, you possibly need to add its file extension: `dwbName = Range("O2").Value & ".xlsx"`. Also, `Range("O2")` is not qualified, we don't know which worksheet (workbook) it belongs to. Think about it and try to clarify. Also, in which workbook is the code located?

Comment: @VBasic2008, code is located in the Book1 from which the values are copied then pasted into the Book2021. basically anything that is written in "O2" should replace the part of code which suggests where to copy so the name of Book2021, to be percise in the original code (line 10) `Set wsDest = Workbooks("ToThere").Worksheets("List1")` that "ToThere" part should be replaced with the  "O2". Workbooks were both open. Code  looks like this: `Dim dwbName As String` `dwbName = Range("O2").Value` `Set wsDest = Workbooks(dwbName).Worksheets("List1")`.

Comment: Does this mean that it is fixed? If not, what exactly is in cell `O2`? Do you want to also replace `FromHere.xlsm`? If so, where is its name? Have you tried `Range("O2").Value & ".xlsx"` (change extension appropriately)?

Comment: @VBasic2008, in `O2` is name to where it should copy, I only need to replace `ToThere.xlsm`. now it is fixed yes, but i want to be dynamic based on what says in O2 so it copies there, I also tried with `Range("O2").Value & ".xlsx"`, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your example

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long
    Dim Name As Integer
    
     Name = Range("O2").Value
    
     'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
      Set wsCopy = Workbooks("FromHere.xlsm").Worksheets("List1")
    
     ' I would like this part here to be: Workbooks(Name).Worksheets("List1")
      Set wsDest = Workbooks("ToThere.xlsx").Worksheets("List1")
    
     '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
      lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in
      'Column A
      'Offset property moves down 1 row
       lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
     '3. Copy & Paste Data
       wsCopy.Range("A2:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Seriously? Think `ActiveSheet.Paste` and `Range("A1").PasteSpecial`.

Comment: I just gave a syntax, but yes I should have given along with an example. Apologies

Comment: There are three ways to copy a range: 1. `srg.Copy dCell`, 2. `srg.Copy: dCell.PasteSpecial: Application.CutCopyMode = False`, and 3. `dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value`. Note the underscore (`_`, the line separator) in OP's code to conclude that he is using the first way. The second way provides many options of how to copy. The third way copies only values, but very efficiently. But all of this has nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: @BigBen, you are right, It's mistake. I Removed it right syntax should have been Range("<range>").PasteSpecial or  ActiveSheet.Paste. Thanks for highlighting it

Comment: @VBasic2008, I think, I have completely misunderstood the question. It's all about making it dynamic. :(. Tilen, would you like to tell what is the dynamic part you are looking for? Is the name of sheets to be dynamic? range to be dynamic?

Comment: @Bharat, i would like the names of workbooks to be dynamic and refrenced to cell "O2", basically whatever is in "O2" should replace the part of code where the name of the workbook is. In the comment above I replied VBasic2008